# Help regarding /odom

Tags: gazebo, ros2, odometry

how do i use /odom as a subscription in python script, i have a controller file in which i have to publish cmd_vel and then move my model. then i have to get the position and velocity back to move further. i cant seem to find how to get position and theta using /odom. this is the code i have written so far.

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__("controller_car")
  
    self.cmd_vel_pub_ = self.create_publisher(Twist, "/cmd_vel", 10)
    self.odom_sub = self.create_subscription(Odometry, "/odom", self.odometryCb, 10)
    self.vel = Twist()

    self.rate = self.create_rate(100)


    self.car_x = 0
    self.car_y = 0
    self.car_theta = 0
    self.x_goals = [1, -1, -1, 1, 0]
    self.y_goals = [1, 1, -1, -1, 0]
    self.theta_goals = [0, math.pi/2, -math.pi, -math.pi/2, 

    self.cli = self.create_client(NextGoal, 'next_goal')      
    self.req = NextGoal.Request() 
    self.index = 0
     
def odometryCb(self,msg):
    #i have to add the code here, so that i can get values of x,y,theta from /odom
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

To access position values as in x-y-z:

```
   pos_x = msg.pose.pose.position.x
   pos_y = msg.pose.pose.position.y
   pos_z = msg.pose.pose.position.z
```

To get theta/yaw (assuming you want the values in euler format, not quaternion which are given by default):

```
   or_x  = msg.pose.pose.orientation.x
   or_y  = msg.pose.pose.orientation.y
   or_z  = msg.pose.pose.orientation.z
   or_w  = msg.pose.pose.orientation.w
   # To transform these to euler format
   roll, pitch, yaw = euler_from_quaternion([or_x, or_y, or_z, or_w])
```

The function *euler_from_quaternion* can be used by:

```
   from tf.transformations import euler_from_quaternion
```